# Кто такой Ешкин Кот?

Tags: фразеология

Мы говорим "ешкин кот", когда хотим выразить досаду на что-то. А кто он такой, этот ешкин кот, откуда пошло выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ёшка, правильнее - Ёжка, "народное" уменьшительное от "Яга" - в нарицательном значении нечто, насылающее порчу (сам вид порчи варьируется, подробнее - у Фасмера). В том числе и та Яга, которая "баба". Эвфемистическое толкование - позднейшее.
Более того, прежде чем стать эвфемизмом слово, видимо, испытало сильное влияние созвучных слов - имен собственных и нарицательных, вполне благопристойного значения. Многочисленные версии того, каких именно, легко находятся в сети; не привожу, ибо крайне недостоверно.

Тут, имхо, гораздо интереснее сам кот. То ли он в прямом значении (и у какой же ведьмы нет кота?), то ли сам по себе замена чего-то утраченного... Подобно тому, как это произошло в "сукин кот".

Comment: Кстати, мне попадалась версия про Кота-Баюна - спутника Бабы Яги

Comment: А запросто. Правда насчет "спутника" - это, имхо, перебор... Это пресонаж достаточно самостоятельный. Хотя часто и появляется в паре Ягой.

Answer (score 4):

"Ёшкин кот" стал знаменитым после выхода фильма "Любовь и голуби". Это одно из многих выражений, которые используют для замены мата, слово-паразит. Такое же, как, например, "ёлки-палки", "ёлки зеленые", "ё-мое", "ёпсель-мопсель".

Примечательно, что большинство подобных слов начинаются с буквы Ё. Видимо, именно этот звук обычно вырывается у русского человека, когда захватывают эмоции.

Comment: В крайнем случае - "я", "Японский городовой". 
А вот интересно, почему именно _ё_ - только ли от глагола - прототипа, или само звучание удобное?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что на "ё" все приведенные выше выражения  это цензурная замена матерному глаголу на "Е" (в разговорном сокращенном варианте  на "ё") с продолженнием. В фильме нельзя было использовать мат, вот и заменили на просторечные цензурные ругательства))))

Comment: "Яп" в безударном слоге звучит так же как "ёп". Вот и все.

Answer (score 2):

Ёжкин кот, так же как: ип-атьевская летопись, бляха-муха,блин,пипец,песец, ёшкин кот, ядрёна вошь, ёж твою медь (ёрш твою медь), япона мать, японский городовой, ядрёный корень (ядрена-корень), ядрён-батон, едрён-матрён, ёкарный бабай, грёбаный и многое другое - всё это эвфемизмы матерных слов и выражений. И не более .А то пошли буквы-звуки, популярный фильм, эмоции на букву "ё"...

Answer (score 0):

Из русского языка на протяжении многих веков исчезали буквы. Это происходило по разным причинам, но в большинстве случаев потому, что эти буквы считались лишними и ненужными. Наши предки были намного умнее нас, и азбуку составляли, опираясь на очень важные факты, ныне почти утерянные.
У человека появилась потребность, либо наследственная необходимость, произносить слова со множеством йотированных звуков (е, ё, ю, я, й) и шипящих согласных.
Примерами такой необходимости можно считать многочисленные фразы: ей-ей, ей-богу, ёшкин кот, ёлки зелёные, юху, уау, япона-мать, японский городовой.
В матерных словах также можно заметить йотированные звуки. Примеров приводить не буду, ибо нецензурно.

Comment: Мария, а какая связь всего этого с Ешкиным котом?

Answer (score 0):

Поражает, что при таком количестве ответов (пять!) никто не ответил на сам вопрос "кто такой ёшкин кот". Зато стали говорить очевидную информацию о современном значении этого выражения.

Нет сомнения в том, что это кот бабы Яги. Сама Яга — персонаж с широкими корнями. С одной стороны её образ полон похоронных атрибутов, распространённых у наших предков, в связи с чем это существо  — посредник между мирами живых и мёртвых. Но в то же время исследователи русских верований обнаруживают в том же персонаже отголоски древнего змеиного культа (см. "Русские суеверия", Власова Марина).

Ёшкиным котом ошибочно называют кота Баюна. Он никогда не был частью каноничного русского фольклора. Этот образ изобретён Афанасьевым на основе разных персонажей (кот-сказочник [баить], колыбельный кот [баюкать] и, возможно, другие). А последующие авторы "свели" кота с Ягой. Цитирую Королёва:

> В афанасьевском варианте Баюн не связан напрямую с ягой (говорится
> лишь, что герою поручают добыть кота по совету «старой колдуньи»),
> другие сказки подчеркивают связь кота, обыкновенно черного, и ведьмы .
> Так, в тексте N 103 из того же сборника кот стережет избушку яги
> («будет глаза драть» всем незваным гостям) . В N 137 змеиха (вариант
> колдуньи-яги) держит при себе питомца, именуемого «котик пегий лобок».
> В сказке о Воле Воловиче людоед «Котище, вытаращи глазища» — ведьмин
> зверь: только сняв с кота шкуру и надев эту шкуру на себя, герой может
> попасть в избушку на курьих ножках, где Баба-яга принимает его за
> «котиньку-батиньку», своего подручного.

Здесь важно добавить, что кот у бабы Яги появляется под влиянием европейских сказаний о ведьмах. Сама Яга изначально не была злой колдуньей, и кота у неё не было. А когда кот появился, то это был другой кот, а не Баюн. Вот то и был тот самый, исконный ёшкин кот, уже не исконной Ёжки.

> выше отмечалась парность кота и яги в русских народных сказках, однако
> в большинстве случаев этот кот безымянный, а если и носит имя или
> прозвище, оно никак не связано с функцией убаюкивания.

> интернет-источники, ссылаясь друг на друга, утверждают, что Баюн как
> помощник яги фигурирует в сказках «Баба-яга и Кот Баюн» и «Иван-дурак
> и Баба-яга», но в классических сборниках народных сказок таких текстов
> нет. (Зато есть «развивающий», как он позиционируется создателями,
> мультфильм для детей «Баба-Яга и кот Баюн». Поскольку массовая
> культура не делает различия между источниками информации и не
> предусматривает оценку их достоверности, не исключено, что эта
> анимационная контаминация или авторская стилизация ряда фольклорных и
> псевдофольклорных сюжетов стала основанием для укоренения подобной
> трактовки в современном коллективном знании

Возможным прототипом Баюна я бы назвал котов из позднего европейского фольклора. Там есть царь котов, например. Но на "людоеда Баюна" более походит исландский Йольский кот. Это громадный кот-людоед. А это уже XIX век, между прочим. Кстати, более созвучно ёшкиному коту.

Что касается того, откуда пошло это выражение, сказать не могу. Но в 1954 году оно уже употреблялось в произведении «Путёвка на целину».

Подытожить хочется фразой Королёва о том, что Баюн вполне соответствует вновь актуализированному запросу на конструирование национальной культурной памяти и национальной идентичности, существующему в современном социуме.